# Sorting nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm using javascript to sort nested arrays. This works as I expect it to:

```
arr = [[223, "VA", "BP8"], [24, "VA", "BP31"], [127, "VA", "BP1"]]

arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[2] > b[2];
});

//[[127, "VA", "BP1"], [24, "VA", "BP31"], [223, "VA", "BP8"]]
```

But when I do this in the browser with more data, nothing gets sorted after doing the `sort` function. It remains exactly as it was before calling `sort`. Any idea what's wrong here? The above example is the exact data being sorted on in the below example, each nested array is just longer in length with more data being pushed to it.

```
tableData = [];
arrayUtil.forEach(event.features, function (feature) {
    var rowData = [];
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.OBJECTID);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.StateID);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.Point);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.PatchNum);
    rowData.push(developed(feature.attributes.IsDeveloped));
    rowData.push(cropType(feature.attributes.CropTypeID));
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.CropResidue);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.CnpyOver12);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.CnpyDecid);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.CnpyConif);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.ShrubCover);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.ShbHiStemsDens);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.GrassCover);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.ForbCover);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.FrbAsProtect);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.ForbSpecies);
    rowData.push(feature.attributes.BareGround);
    rowData.push(herbHght(feature.attributes.HerbHeight));
    var overstoryDesc = coarseClassify(feature.attributes.Overstory);
    rowData.push(overstoryDesc);
    rowData.push(fineClassify(feature.attributes.Understory, overstoryDesc));
    rowData.push(qhStatus(feature.attributes.OfficialQH));
    rowData.push(formatDate(feature.attributes.ObsvDate));
    rowData.push(collectionType(feature.attributes.ObsvType));
    tableData.push(rowData);
});

//Sort the tableData list of lists by Point name
tableData.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[2] > b[2];
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function to `.sort()` should return a **number**, not a boolean. The number should be less than zero to indicate that the two values are already in the proper order, or greater than zero to indicate that they are in reverse order, or zero to indicate that they're equivalent.

Thus what you want is something like

```
tableData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[2].localeCompare(b[2]);
});
```

The string `.localeCompare()` function does exactly the thing that you want for a sort comparator. However, you may see older string-based comparator functions that do something like this:

```
tableData.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

which is more explicit.

*edit* — now that I re-examine the original code in the question, it may be that you want to sort in *reverse* order of that key. If that's the case, you can simply negate the call to `.localeCompare()` or compare `b` to `a` instead of `a` to `b`.